# Apple Mail.app set HTML signature with plugin

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa

I've created a Mail.app plugin with Python to set a custom signature pulled from a remote server by swizzling the setSignature: method in ComposeBackEnd. As per the class dump below, I can set a plain text signature by using setSignatureContents: and this is functional.

```
@interface Signature : NSObject <NSCopying>
{
    NSString *_uniqueId;
    NSString *_name;
    NSData *_webArchiveData;
    BOOL _isRich;
    BOOL _isSavedAsRich;
    BOOL _isDirty;
    MFSyncedFile *_syncedFile;
}

- (id)syncedFile;
- (id)signaturePath;
- (unsigned long long)hash;
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)isRich;
- (void)setIsRich:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setWebArchive:(id)arg1;
- (id)webArchive;
- (id)webArchiveData;
.....
- (void)setSignatureContents:(id)arg1;
- (id)signatureContents;
- (void)setSignatureName:(id)arg1;
- (id)signatureName;

@end
```

However when I attempt to set an HTML signature using setWebArchive: (which should take an NSData object):

```
signature.setWebArchive_(NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL_(NSURL.URLWithString_('http://...')))
```

I get the following error:

```
11/7/12 11:07:38.858 AM Mail[8820]: -[NSConcreteData data]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffc2386bc00
```

(The remote file is already in the correct format)

Is there any way to make this work? Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT - tried this (returns WebArchive object which should respond to `-[data]`):

```
wds = WebDataSource.alloc().initWithRequest_(NSURLRequest.requestWithURL_(NSURL.URLWithString_('http://...')))
        webarchive = wds.webArchive
        signature.setWebArchive_(webarchive)
```

result:

```
11/7/12 3:26:59.173 PM Mail[16814]: An uncaught exception was raised
11/7/12 3:26:59.173 PM Mail[16814]: Class OC_PythonObject: no such selector: data
```

Comment: Are you sure `-[setWebArchive:]` takes an `NSData` rather than taking anything that responds to the `-[data]` message with an `NSData`? Because it sure looks like it's trying to call `-[data]` on your object, hence the unrecognized selector error.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for the tip, there's a WebArchive class in the WebKit framework that responds to -[data], however updating the code to use it resulted in the same error.

Comment: Are you sure `webarchive` responds to `-[data]`? What happens if you just do `d = webarchive.data()` in Python?

Comment: Actually, I think that's the problem: If `WebDataSource` is like `Signature`, it has a `webArchive` method, not a `webArchive` property. If so, `wds.webArchive` returns a PyObjC object representing the ObjC equivalent of a bound method, and you can't call `data` on that. You may have wanted `webarchive = wds.webArchive()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However when I attempt to set an HTML signature using setWebArchive: (which should take an NSData object)… I get the following error:

```
11/7/12 11:07:38.858 AM Mail[8820]: -[NSConcreteData data]: unrecognized selector
```

This error is telling you that `-[setWebArchive:]` is trying to call `-[data]` on your `NSData` object. Since `-[NSData data]` doesn't exist, you get an unrecognized selector exception.

Clearly it doesn't take an `NSData`, it takes something that responds to `-[data]` by returning an `NSData`.

> EDIT - tried this (returns WebArchive object which should respond to -[data]):

```
wds = WebDataSource.alloc().initWithRequest_(NSURLRequest.requestWithURL_(NSURL.URLWithString_('http://...')))
webarchive = wds.webArchive
signature.setWebArchive_(webarchive)
```

Hold on… you haven't shown the class dump for this one, but the other class has a method `-[webArchive]`, not a properly `webArchive`. So, if they're at all consistent, this one is also likely to have a method, not a property.

If so, this means `wds.webArchive` is not going to be a a `WebArchive` object, it's going to be a wrapper object that represents roughly the ObjC equivalent of a Python bound method. And calling `-[data]` on that thing will almost certainly fail.

```
11/7/12 3:26:59.173 PM Mail[16814]: Class OC_PythonObject: no such selector: data
```

If you just change that to `wds.webArchive()`, that should fix the problem.

Finally, it's worth doing a bit of debugging prints here. If you think you've got a `WebArchive` and `-[WebArchive data]` returns an `NSData`, you can test that really easily:

```
print webArchive
print webArchive.data()
```

Comment: Thank you - I overlooked the () being that I'm not familiar with python, it sets a WebArchive object without exceptions now but doesn't actually set the signature in the Mail so I'll investigate more.

Comment: Learning PyObjC when you're not familiar with Python must be a whole lot of fun… Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking to do this, here's the solution to create and set a web archive (you'll need to add the WebKit framework):

```
WebView *webView = [[WebView alloc] init];
WebFrame *webFrame = [webView mainFrame];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]];
[webFrame loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

-

```
WebDataSource *webDataSource = webFrame.dataSource;
WebArchive *webArchive = webDataSource.webArchive;
[signature setWebArchive:webArchive];
```

The code above after conversion to PyObjC syntax works great with the latest version of Mail. It can't be a local file unfortunately as Gatekeeper on 10.8 restricts it, and you have to call the URL request prior setSignature: (set webFrame as global variable and subclass the main window loading for instance) otherwise it won't load in time and you'll just get an empty WebArchive.